# Why do I need to take the number of conduction band valleys into account when calculating the Landau Level degeneracy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electrons, semiconductor-physics

I have a question regarding the degernacy of the Landau Levels. On the lecture slides it says that the spin and valley degrees of freedom need to be considered when calculating the degeneracy of Landau Levels.

I do understand why I need to consider the spin degerneracy, as each state can be occupied by two electrons of opposite spin. However, I don´t quite understand why I need to consider the valley degeneracy - as I understand the valleys as being equivalent points within the first Brillouin Zone, but the erergy of the Landau Levels is not dependent on k?

I would really appreciate your help / thoughts / comments! :-)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Does do not the LL calculation assume either a Dirac or Shrodinger approximation to $\epsilon(k)$?  If so each low energy region makes a separate contribution.